# ROS Answers SE migration: cram_tutorials

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm doing the cram_tutorial (EventsCoTeSys-ROS-School Day 4)

And when I do
CL-USER> (ros-load:load-system "cram_tutorials" :cram-pick-and-place)

I have this problem:

component #:APPROACH_TABLE_TOOLS-SRV not found, required by
#<SYSTEM "cram-pick-and-place" {B7A72D1}>
[Condition of type ASDF:MISSING-DEPENDENCY]

What can I do?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11484/cram_tutorials/) by [Sanxano](https://answers.ros.org/users/1103/sanxano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2011-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like messages and services are not built. Try executing

```
rosmake cram_pick_and_plance
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0